# Will my instagram app stop working when legacy api will be disabled?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I found it very hard to understand what exactly will be disabled at the end of March 2020. 
Instagram says that they will disable legacy api but I don't know how to check if it will affect my app. My app use endpoints like: 
 - /v1/users/self/follows?access_token
to check if user is a follower or similar to check user hashtags.

Documentation is very confusing for me. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2019/10/15/launch-instagram-basic-display-api/) on Facebook's developer blog:

> With this migration, the Basic Permission for Instagram Legacy API Platform will be deprecated on March 2, 2020.

(later changed to March 30)

The deprecation of the Basic Permission for the legacy API means that calls to the legacy API will no longer work at all.  So you can no longer make calls to `/v1/users/self/follows?access_token` as of April 1, 2020.  There are relatively significant changes in the new graph API as to what you can access and what permissions are needed to access it.  A good overview of how to get going on their consumer "Basic Display API" is here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api